# How to create a sudorule in freeIPA for the sudoedit builtin

Tags: linux, sudo, freeipa

Currently, when I want to grant some group of users access to edit a file, I proceed as follows:

```
ipa sudocmd-add --desc=Vi IMproved default-mode, no-exec, no-suspend mode' '/usr/bin/rvim'
ipa sudocmdgroup-add edition --desc='commands for restricted edition'
ipa sudocmdgroup-add-member edition --sudocmds=/usr/bin/rvim
ipa sudorule-add edition-4-operators --desc='Operator access to restricted edition commands'
ipa sudorule-add-allow-command edition-4-operators --sudocmdgroups=edition
```

and then the rest of the options related to HBAC, SELinux, etc.

I want to replace `/usr/bin/rvim` with the builtin `sudoedit(8)` in all sudorules of my [freeIPA](http://freeipa.org) server.

Do I need to declare `sudoedit` as a `sudocmd` as usual? Can I directly add `sudoedit` to the `sudocmdgroup` without declaring it as a `sudocmd` previously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to do it (actually, a practical example):

```
#  ipa sudocmd-add --desc='sudoedit configuration file of IPv4 packet filtering and NAT' 'sudoedit /etc/sysconfig/iptables'
--------------------------------------------------------------
Added Sudo Command "sudoedit /etc/sysconfig/iptables"
--------------------------------------------------------------
  Sudo Command: sudoedit /etc/sysconfig/iptables
  Description: sudoedit configuration file of IPv4 packet filtering and NAT

#  ipa sudocmdgroup-add-member networking --sudocmds='sudoedit /etc/sysconfig/iptables'
  Sudo Command Group: networking
  Description: commands for network configuration and troubleshooting
  Member Sudo commands: sudoedit /etc/sysconfig/iptables
-------------------------
Number of members added 1
-------------------------
```

Being sudoedit a sudo builtin

```
# ls -lrt /usr/bin/sudoedit
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Apr  8 09:00 /usr/bin/sudoedit -> sudo*
```

trying to add the sudorule using `/usr/bin/sudoedit` will fail with this error:

```
$ sudo -e /etc/sysconfig/iptables
Sorry, user joe is not allowed to execute 'sudoedit /etc/sysconfig/iptables' as root on host.domain.com.
```

Works correctly for both `sudo -e` and `sudoedit`.